# PHP Passing a class into another class constructor

Tags: php, oop

I am very much pulling my hair out after searching around on Google and this website for a very long time, and cannot seem to do this basic task (Java was very simple) but with PHP I'm having such a hard time.
Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong. All I want is the Job class to be passed into the Person class and for them to link together but I am struggling to grasp it attempting various other routes of achieving it.

```
<?php

class Person{
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name, Job $job){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->job = $job;
    }

    public function display(){
        return $this->name . $this->job;
    }
}

class Job{
    public $job;

    public function __construct($job){
        $this->job = $job;
    }
}

$job = new Job("Programmer");
$person = new Person("John");

echo $person->display();
```

?>

Comment: You are setting $this->job = $job; but you don't have variable $job in Person class

Comment: okay but then if I need to do that then surely I won't need one in the Job class? but the Job class should contain a job so therefore it should as I want it to be passed into the person?

Comment: You say _"All I want is the Job class to be passed into the Person class"_ yet you simply are **not** doing the one thing you actually need to do: **pass the `Job` into the `Person`'s costructor.**

Comment: `return $this->name . $this->job;`.... `$this->job` is an object of type `Job`, what do you expect to happen here? What should concatenating a `Job` object with a string actually do?

Comment: I had passed the job into the person class., and in response to you Mark I assume try to output both together.

Comment: Then you need a mechanism to convert your Job object to a string when used in a context such as  that concatenation or echo; the implementing the `__toString()` magic method will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, do you need to pass a *Job* instance - as dependency - to the *Person* object, if it's only about the job name - like in the following context? I would say not really:

```
class Person {

    /**
     * Person name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Job name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $job;

    /**
     * Person's age.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $age;

    /**
     * Person's place of birth.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $birthPlace;

    /**
     * Job name.
     *
     * @param string $name Person name.
     * @param string $job Job name.
     * @param int $age Person's age.
     * @param string $birthPlace Person's place of birth.
     */
    public function __construct(string $name, string $job, int age, string $birthPlace) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->job = $job;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->birthPlace = $birthPlace;
    }

    /**
     * Get person's details.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDetails() {
        return $this->name . ', ' . $this->job . ', ' . $this->age . ', ' . $this->birthPlace;
    }

}

use Person;

$person = new Person('TLG', 'programmer', 28, 'Paris');

echo $person->getDetails();
```

But what if more specific job details are to be assigned to a person? Then a *Job* instance can be used:

```
/*
 * Job.
 */

class Job {

    /**
     * Job name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Job location.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $name Job name.
     * @param string $location Job location.
     */
    public function __construct(string $name, string $location) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    /**
     * Get the job name.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get the job location.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocation() {
        return $this->location;
    }

}


/*
 * Person.
 */

use Job;

class Person {

    /**
     * Person name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Job instance.
     *
     * @var Job
     */
    private $job;

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $name Person name.
     * @param Job $job Job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(string $name, Job $job) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->job = $job;
    }

    /**
     * Get person's details.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDetails() {
        return $this->name . ', ' . $this->job->getName() . ' in ' . $this->job->getLocation();
    }

}


/*
 * The call.
 */

use Job;
use Person;

$job = new Job('Programmer', 'London');
$person = new Person('John', $job);

echo $person->getDetails();
```

**Notes:**

- You should make all properties *private*. For the ones needed to be accessible from outside create public *getters/setters*, in order to ensure [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).
- You should use namespaces. In this case, since both classes are defined in the [global namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php), you don't need to import any classes, e.g. use the statements beginning with the *use* keyword. Though, in other situations, where defining *top-level namespaces* and *subnamespaces* is needed, then you should definitely make use of import statements. They will give you a very elegant way of manipulating class names and increase the readability of your class codes. See [PSR-1: Basic Coding Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/), [PSR-2: Coding Style Guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), [PSR-4: Autoloader](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Now, what if a person can have multiple jobs? Then you could use a *JobCollection*:

```
 /*
 * Job.
 */

class Job {

    // Same as above...

}


/*
 * Job collection.
 */

use Job;

class JobCollection {

    /**
     * Jobs list.
     *
     * @var Job[]
     */
    private $jobs = [];

    /**
     * Add a job.
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function add(Job $job) {
        $this->jobs[] = $job;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get all jobs.
     * 
     * @return Job[]
     */
    public function all() {
        return $this->jobs;
    }

}


/*
 * Person.
 */

use JobCollection;

class Person {

    /**
     * Person name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Job collection.
     *
     * @var JobCollection
     */
    private $jobs;

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $name Person name.
     * @param JobCollection $jobs Job collection.
     */
    public function __construct(string $name, JobCollection $jobs) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->jobs = $jobs;
    }

    /**
     * Get the person name.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get the person's jobs.
     * 
     * @return Job[]
     */
    public function getJobs() {
        return $this->jobs->all();
    }

    /**
     * Get person's details.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDetails() {
        $result = $this->getName() . '<br/>';

        foreach ($this->jobs->all() as $job) {
            $result .= $job->getName() . ' in ' . $job->getLocation() . '<br/>';
        }

        return $result;
    }

}


/*
 * The call.
 */

use Job;
use Person;
use JobCollection;

// Create some jobs.
$job1 = new Job('Programmer', 'London');
$job2 = new Job('Bartender', 'Paris');

// Create the job collection and add the jobs to it.
$jobs = new JobCollection();
$jobs
        ->add($job1)
        ->add($job2)
;

// Create the person.
$person = new Person('John', $jobs);

echo $person->getDetails();
```

The [Law of Demeter](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/18/breaking-the-law-of-demeter-is-like-looking-for-a-needle-in-the-haystack/), as greatly presented in [The Clean Code Talks - Don't Look For Things!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0), specifies that you should only inject dependencies which are directly used by a class. E.g. you shouldn't pass dependencies having the role of intermediaries, e.g. which are only used to create other objects whos methods you need to call.

In the earlier version of my answer I gave you the impression that it's false to use a *Job* instance in a *Person* object in order to assign the job name. It is correct to use a *Job* instance. By using it you are not breaking the *LoD* per se, but only the nuance of it, that you don't really need a *Job* instance in order to assign a job name to a *Person* object (as in my first example) if the job doesn't imply a more specifical case (as in the second example and in your good question in the comment).

Comment: makes sense thanks for your response. Btw why must I use 'use' when the objects have already been instantiated? Okay and I haven't broken the law of demeter right by passing Job into the person constructor? or only the job name attribute?

Comment: okay that makes sense I appreciate your response. However, when you say only pass it the name, is that what we're doing here with getJob(), and say if we had another job attribute of "location" (which has a seperate get function), we would only use getJob() and not getLocation() too if you know what I;m trying to say?

Comment: @aebdeerei I tried your code above and it does not seem to be working?

Comment: ah nvm it was because you had "string name" and "string job" and doesn't work?

Comment: @TLG123 Yes, I changed a bit: in the _Job_ class there is now the property _name_ instead of _job_ (like you named it). I did it because I found it semantically better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

class Person
{
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name, \Job $job)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->job  = $job;
    }

    public function display()
    {
        return $this->name . $this->job;
    }
}

class Job
{
    public $job;

    public function __construct($job)
    {
        $this->job = $job;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->job;
    }
}

$job    = new Job("Programmer");
$person = new Person("John", $job);

echo $person->display();
```

Comment: ah right thank you so I needed to convert my return output into a string?

Answer (score 0):

your are missing a Job object in your Person class, and then you should assign  the Job pass to the Person object on the job variable .

for example :

```
<?php

class Person
{
    public $name;
    private $job;

    public function __construct($name, Job $job)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->job  = $job;
    }

    public function display()
    {
        return $this->name ." ". $this->job->job;
    }
}

class Job
{
    public $job;

    public function __construct($job)
    {
        $this->job = $job;
    }

}

$job = new Job("Programmer");
$person = new Person("John", $job);

echo $person->display();
```

?>